# Oracle - Column NUMBER(38) in WHERE clause - data has comma

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, nls-comp

I am trying to query a table with a where clause on a Column Data Type NUMBER(38) . Since it is a NUMBER (as shown in below format) This would not work

```
SELECT * FROM PAT WHERE ID='1,234'
```

So I converted the String using `TO_NUMBER & NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER ('1,234', '9G999',
   'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''') AS FROM Dual;
```

output: `1,234`

But, I am not sure how to use this in a `WHERE` clause as I get:

> INVALID IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use strings for numbers. Use a proper number constant:

```
select  * 
from PAT 
where ID = 1.234
```

Numbers must not be enclosed in single quotes. In SQL the decimal separator is a `.`

See the manual for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220

Comment: I am not actually using Strings for numbers. I just gave the first query for illustration. Unfortunately the data doesn't have a DOT(.) It has a COMMA(,). This didn't work either- select  * 
from PAT 
where ID = 1,234

Comment: @pingu: well `1,234` is not a valid number literal in SQL. You have to use a `.` for the decimal. I don't understand what you mean with "*the data doesn't have a dot*" - we are talking about a query, not "data".

Comment: It was my Bad. This query with out dot worked - select  * 
from PAT 
where ID = 1234

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a subquery may work:

```
select  * from PAT where ID IN (Select TO_NUMBER ('1,234', '9G999',
   'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''') as from Dual;
```